# I have updated the data on github but node module request still get old data

Tags: node.js, caching, request

I put some data on github.
and I use node module "request" to get data from it.
After I update my data on github.
nodejs still get old data for about five minutes.
This is part of my code.

```
var url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Larry850806/facebook-chat-bot/master/db.json";
request({ url: url, json: true }, function(error, response, body){
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(body); // Print the json response
        // after I update data, body still get old data
    }
});
```

I think it's because there is a cache.
So I can't not get "real" data but the old one.
Is there any way to get the newest data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed a Github cache. One thing you might want to try is to append a random querystring onto the end of the file you're requesting.

For instance:

```
var url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Larry850806/facebook-chat-bot/master/db.json?random=<randomnumberhere>";
request({ url: url, json: true }, function(error, response, body){
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log(body); // Print the json response
        // after I update data, body still get old data
    }
});
```

This sometimes 'forces' the backend server to break the cache (if they are looking for querystrings).